# Pivoting for DATEPART(wk, date)

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like this,

mytable

```
date       | value
2018.09.12 |  1
2018.09.11 |  2
2018.09.10 |  3
```

I need a query to return sum(value) for the last six weeks. Exactly like this.

```
week# | value
 37   |  6
 36   |  0
 35   |  0
 34   |  8
 33   |  9
 32   |  10
 31   |  11
```

I have a query to return sumvalue for each week.

```
SELECT Sum(Value) AS Sumvalue,  DATEPART(wk, date) AS [weekNo]
FROM mytable
WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -42, GETDATE()) AND  GETDATE() 
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)
```

But this can't handle zero values for a week.

How can write a pivoted query to obtain the format?

My try;

```
SELECT *
FROM (
           SELECT Value,  DATEPART(wk, date) AS [weekNo]
           FROM mytable
           WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -42, GETDATE()) AND  GETDATE() 
     ) As sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    Sum(Value) for DATEPART(wk, date) IN (SELECT date FROM mytable where date between 
                            DATEADD(DAY, -42, GETDATE()) and   GETDATE())
) AS pivotable
```

I am getting the syntax error near for keyword. How can I put the six weeks in pivot statemet

Comment: I already have. See the table with week#, please.

Comment: You cannot write a single query which will generate different result sets with different *column names*, which is what you appear to be trying to do with your pivot

Comment: since the parameter is always between today and today - six weeks, is there a way to hard code in for statements?

Answer (score 1):

Found a partial solution!

```
SELECT *
FROM (
           SELECT Value,  DATEPART(wk, date) AS [weekNo]
           FROM mytable
           WHERE Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -42, GETDATE()) AND  GETDATE() 
     ) As sourcetable
PIVOT
(
    Sum(Value) for [week] IN ([1], [2], [3], ... ,[54])
) AS pivotable
```

It is partial since it is kind of hardcoding the for statement and cannot control the unnecessary weeks in the query.

Comment: for getting 6 weeks ago you can do this..select dateadd(WEEK, -6, getdate()) then is any reson for using  select DATEADD(DAY, -42, GETDATE())